# Lit JS - Issue with event.target in document.addEventListener

Tags: web-component, lit, lit-html

If i am using document listener anywhere in Lit Js and try to console event.target then it is printing only current element object instead of element which user has clicked.

```
connectedCallback() {
    document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
       console.log(event.target);
    });
}
```

How to achieve this functionality in Lit? Is it a defect?

Comment: you need ``composed:true`` on (custom) Events to pierce upward through shadowDOM

Comment: curious if you tried `event.currentTarget` to see if it has your expected target?

Comment: To see all DOM elements under your click location use ``event.composedPath()``. Note it is better to avoind ``event`` and use ``evt`` because for historical IE reasons ``event`` is a global variable, with the same content